# How to solve transient 3D heat equation with robin boundary conditions

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, piecewise, boundary-conditions

Good afternoon!

I'm trying to solve the following heat equation:

[image]

with the following boundary conditions and initial value:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Nut I'm getting error while solving it with NDSolve:

```
s = NDSolve[{(1.0/alpha) D[T[x, y, z, t], t] == 
D[T[x, y, z, t], {x, 2}] + D[T[x, y, z, t], {y, 2}] + 
 D[T[x, y, z, t], {z, 2}],T[x, y, z, 0] == T0, -lambda D[T[x, y, 0, t], z] ==Piecewise[{{qmax Exp[-c ((x - xs0 - vx t)^2 + y^2)/r0^2], (x - xs0 - vx t)^2 + y^2 <=r0^2}, {-h (T[x, y, 0, t] - Tinf), (x - xs0 - vx t)^2 + y^2 >r0^2}}],lambda D[T[0, y, z, t], x] == h (T[0, y, z, t] - Tinf), -lambda D[T[L, y, z, t], x] == h (T[L, y, z, t] - Tinf), D[T[x, 0, z, t], y] == 0, -lambda D[T[x, W/2, z, t], y] == h (T[x, W/2, z, t] - Tinf), -lambda D[T[x, y, H, t], z] == h (T[x, y, H, t] - Tinf)}, T, {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, W}, {z, 0, H}, {t, 0, tf}]
```

Could someone help?
Full code here: https://pastebin.com/U0qhNSeJ

Comment: You need to define all parameters `tf, alpha,lamda,...` before `NDSolve` is applied.

Comment: You might increase the chance to get a helpful answer if you provide complete executable code! Together with some information about the errors.

Comment: Full code here: https://pastebin.com/U0qhNSeJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We must change everything to meters. I updated the code and added a step function `f[x]`, changed the boundary condition for `y = 0` to `Automatic` (=`NeumannValue[0, y==0]`). Now all the pictures are in real time (sec) and in meters.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
L = 1000(*scale*);
(*Plate dimensions*)Ls = 250/L;
W = 200/L;
H = 30/L; reg = Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {Ls, W, H}]; mesh = 
 ToElementMesh[reg, MaxCellMeasure -> .0000005];
mesh["Wireframe"]
(*Material properties*)
rhocp = 4898556;
lambda = 36;
alpha = 1; ts = (lambda/rhocp)^(-1)(*time scale*);

T0 = 293(*Initial temperature*); Tinf = 293(*Ambient temperature*); Q \
= 4256(*Source power*); xs0 = 
 6/L(*Initial position of moving source*); xsf = (Ls - 
   xs0)(*final position of moving source*); r0 = 
 3/L(*radius of source*); c = 1(*source constant parameter*); vx = 
 ts 1.61/L(*moving source velocity x direction. Velocity *); qmax = 
 c Q/(Pi r0^2)/lambda(*source term*); h = 
 10/lambda(*heat convection coeffcient*); tf = (Ls - 2 xs0)/
  vx(*Final time of calculation*);(*eq={(1.0/alpha) D[T[x,y,z,t],t]\
\[Equal]D[T[x,y,z,t],{x,2}]+D[T[x,y,z,t],{y,2}]+D[T[x,y,z,t],{z,2}],,-\
lambda D[T[x,y,0,t],z]\[Equal]Piecewise[{{qmax Exp[-c ((x-xs0-vx \
t)^2+y^2)/r0^2],(x-xs0-vx t)^2+y^2\[LessEqual]r0^2},{-h \
(T[x,y,0,t]-Tinf),(x-xs0-vx t)^2+y^2>r0^2}}],lambda D[T[0,y,z,t],x]\
\[Equal]h (T[0,y,z,t]-Tinf),-lambda D[T[L,y,z,t],x]\[Equal]h \
(T[L,y,z,t]-Tinf),D[T[x,0,z,t],y]\[Equal]0,-lambda D[T[x,W/2,z,t],y]\
\[Equal]h (T[x,W/2,z,t]-Tinf),-lambda D[T[x,y,H,t],z]\[Equal]h \
(T[x,y,H,t]-Tinf)}*)
f[x_] := (1 + Tanh[10000 x])/2
eq = D[T[x, y, z, t], 
    t] - (D[T[x, y, z, t], {x, 2}] + D[T[x, y, z, t], {y, 2}] + 
     D[T[x, y, z, t], {z, 2}]);

ic = T[x, y, z, 0] == T0; bc = 
 NeumannValue[
   qmax Exp[-c ((x - xs0 - vx t)^2 + y^2)/r0^2] f[
      r0^2 - (x - xs0 - vx t)^2 - y^2] - 
    h (T[x, y, z, t] - Tinf) f[((x - xs0 - vx t)^2 + y^2) - r0^2], 
   z == 0] + 
  NeumannValue[-h (T[x, y, z, t] - Tinf), 
   x == 0 || x == Ls || y == W || z == H];

sol = NDSolve[{eq == bc, ic}, 
  T, {t, 0, tf}, {x, y, z} \[Element] mesh]
Table[DensityPlot[
  Evaluate[T[x, y, 0, t] /. sol], {x, 0, Ls}, {y, 0, W}, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  FrameLabel -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> Row[{"t =", t ts}], 
  PlotRange -> All], {t, .2 tf, tf, .2 tf}]

Table[DensityPlot[
  Evaluate[T[x, 0, z, t] /. sol], {x, 0, Ls}, {z, 0, H}, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", FrameLabel -> Automatic], {t, .2 tf, 
  tf, .2 tf}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

We have nice pictures at `z=H`

```
Table[DensityPlot[
  Evaluate[T[x, y, H, t] /. sol], {x, 0, Ls}, {y, 0, W}, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  FrameLabel -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> Row[{"t =", t ts}], 
  PlotRange -> All], {t, .2 tf, tf, .2 tf}]
```

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: Dear Alex, thank you very much for the solution! I'm new with Mathematica and I think I haven't understood all the steps you did. For example, on `eq` there is only one minus sign on the x derivative, should it also be negative for the y and z derivatives?
I don't understand the boundary conditions... does one  `NeumannValue[h (T[x, y, z, t] - Tinf), True]` accounts the convection on all surfaces? For the heat source term I couldn't follow how you did. Could you please help me? Thank you!

Comment: 1. `eq` has a form `D[T[x, y, z, t]-(…)`, and bracket `()` has the same meaning as in standard calculus. 2.  I usually use `True` in such problems. But you can replace it with  `bc=NeumannValue[…,z==0]+NeumannValue[-h (T[x, y, z, t] - Tinf), x==0||y==0||x==Ls||y==W||z==H]` and compare. 3. There is a thin source of radius `r0` and a mesh with a mesh size of `r0`. Effectively, the source heats one cell. On the next cell we have `Exp[-8]=0.000335463`, there the cooling is turned on as `(1-Exp[-8])`.

Comment: Is it possible to use the `Piecewise[...]` function to define the moving source as I did or NDSolve will raise error with it? Another problem is the symmetry bc at y=0, since the moving source is located at the center, i.e. at position W/2, for this case is it possible to also set .`NeumannValue[0, y==0]`?
This is a Welding simulation and I'm also trying to solve it with finite difference method using ADI Douglas-Gunn method + TDMA.

Comment: @JoãoVitor If this is welding, then explain what material it is and in what units the parameters are expressed?

Comment: L, W, H, xs0, xsf and r0 in mm.
tf in seconds.
vx in mm/s.
T0 and Tinf in °C.
qmax in W.
Q in J.
c is dimensionless.
lambda in W/m.K
h in W/m².K
rhocp in J/m³.K

Comment: Then we must change everything to meters. I updated the code and added a step function `f[x]`, changed the boundary condition for y = 0 to `Automatic` (=NeumannValue[0, y==0]) . Now all the pictures are in real time (sec) and in meters.

Comment: Thank you very much Alex! How can I plot the entire plate? The code calculates half of teh plate, due to the symmetry. It would be very nice to show the full plate...

Comment: @JoãoVitor Use `Table[DensityPlot[
  Evaluate[T[x, Abs[y], H, t] /. sol], {x, 0, Ls}, {y,-W, W}, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  FrameLabel -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> Row[{"t =", t ts}], 
  PlotRange -> All], {t, .2 tf, tf, .2 tf}]`